# How to always use git mergetool to merge?

Tags: git

I am managing a repo where people in my team often submit codes that should be discarded. When I do a git pull, it automatically merge the files and it is annoying to go into each files to delete the codes. I use command line and gitkraken to manage the repo. Is it possible to stop auto merge and require each pull with mergetool?

Comment: As others also advise in their answers, the solution is as easy as not using `git pull` any more. Use `git fetch` then inspect the changes on the fetched branches and merge them only if you are happy with them.

Comment: Then that still requires manual insertions and deletions instead of mergetool-like features.

Comment: The idea is to not ask Git to do the merge (this is what `git pull` does) but to let it only do `git fetch` and do the merge yourself. It doesn't exclude the usage of any merge tool you prefer.

Comment: If I understand correctly I must run `git merge` after `git fetch` in order to see the newly fetched files.

Comment: No. `git fetch` brings into the local repository the commits from the remote repository and the remote branches that point to them. You can use the remote branches to access these commits and inspect them. There is no need to merge. `git merge` creates a new commit that brings into your current branch the changes introduced by other branches (no matter if they are local or remote).

Comment: Still, if I use git fetch, how do I activated the mergetool to select changes I desire?

Comment: Instead of `git pull origin branch1` you can do `git fetch origin branch1` then `git diff branch1 origin/branch1` to check the differences. Or use a GUI Git client. Or the compare & merge tool of your choice.

Comment: Then that is still not the outcome I desire. I want to trigger git mergetool instead of manually changing them after looking through git diff...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could just use `git revert` after the merge to undo those commits whose code you don't want?

Answer (score 0):

I guess would be related to git workflows and how to manage a repo in a development team by defining various branches for `dev`, `mainstream` and etc.

You can read about it [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows).

Basically, what development team do is creating subbranch from the stable branch before starting their development (let's call it `dev-featureX`) and once development was completed, changes are pushed to the same branch on the remote server (in our case: `origin/dev-featureX`). 
Repo maintainer (in our case means you) pull all the branches in its client:

```
git pull
```

checkout to recently published branch:

```
git checkout dev-featureX
```

Review and audit the codes and changes and finally merge approved changes to the main branch (imagine in our case, dev branch):

```
git merge dev-featureX dev
```

Note that, the easiest workflow to manage called `Centralized-workflow` which has a similar approach to traditional VCS like SVN.

Comment: The thing is...`git merge dev-featureX dev` does the merge automatically, so I like it to stop and let me use mergetool to complete the merge.

Comment: What do you mean by stop the merge? git mergetool just shows up in case of conflict in order to resolve them manually, if your intention is selecting which files should go into target branch then you need to make a temporary branch to pick your desired files from dev branch and ultimately merge it to your main.

Comment: Yes I want mergetool to shows up on every file and every merge as if there is always a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using `git pull`.  All it does is run two other Git commands.  If you run the two other commands yourself, you have more control.

First, run `git fetch` to bring over the new code.

Then, run `git merge --no-commit` to merge without committing.  You may now run additional commands.  However, note that `git mergetool` assumes that anything Git merged by itself is correctly merged, and does not offer re-merging of these files.

Comment: That isn't exactly the result I desired, I want mergetool to shows up on every file and every merge as if there is always a conflict.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't *get* that with Git. You can get closer: you can write your own script that re-computes the merge base, then inspects the tree content of the base, the `HEAD` commit, and the `MERGE_HEAD` commit. Where the three hashes for any one file differ, but there's only a stage-zero entry in the index, Git must have merged that file. But this misses some cases (e.g., file added only on one "side" of the merge, and trickiest, detected renames). In addition, if the merge was done recursively, there is no single merge base in the first place. So it will be imperfect no matter what.